# Ring isomorphism between $(k[x,y]/(xy))/(x+y-a)$ and $k\times k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem, polynomial-rings, ring-isomorphism

Let $k$ be a field and let $a\in k$ be a non zero element. Consider the quotient ring $A = k[x,y]/(xy)$. If $f\in k[x,y]$ we denote by $\overline{f}$ its image in $A$. Now consider the quotient ring $B = A/(\overline{x+y-a})$. I want to show that $B$ is isomorphic, as a ring, to $k\times k$.

Here is my attempt: Consider the ring homomorphism
$$
k[x,y]\to k\times k, \quad f(x,y)\mapsto (f(a,0),f(0,a)).
$$
Its kernel crearly contains $(xy)$ so it induces a homomorphism
$$
\varphi':A \to k\times k, \quad \overline{f(x,y)} \mapsto (f(a,0),f(0,a)).
$$
Finally, it is clear that the kernel of this homomorphism contains $I=(\overline{x+y-a})$ so it induces a ring homomorphism
$$
\varphi:B\to k\times k, \quad \overline{f(x,y)}+I \mapsto (f(a,0),f(0,a)).
$$
It is easy to see that $\varphi$ is surjective. So I need to show that this is injective or, equivalently, that $\ker(\varphi')=I$. Here is where I'm stuck.

I also tried by defining
$$
\eta:k\times k\to B, \quad (r,s) \mapsto \overline{a^{-1}(rx+sy)}.
$$
This can be shown (by using the defining relations of $B$) to be a ring homomorphism and we have that $\varphi\circ\eta$ is the identity map. Thus we can try by proving that $\eta\circ \varphi$ is the identity map. I'm stuck here too.

Another attempt is the following: Intuitively, the relation $\overline{x}= \overline{a} - \overline{y}$ tells me that we can conjecture the isomorphism
$$
B\cong k[x]/(x(x-a)),
$$
by first defining
$$
k[x,y]\to k[x]/(x(x-a)), \quad f(x,y)\mapsto f(x,a-x), 
$$
which clearly induces a homomorphism
$$
A\to k[x]/(x(x-a)),
$$
which in turn induces
$$
\theta: B\to k[x]/(x(x-a)).
$$
Now the aim is to prove that this last map is a ring isomorphism. If done, then as $(x)$ and $(x-a)$ are comaximal ideals, the Chinese Remainder Theorem implies that
$$
k[x]/(x(x-a)) \cong \frac{k[x]}{(x)}\times \frac{k[x]}{(x-a)}\cong k\times k
$$
and we are done. But I don't know how to show that $\theta$ is an isomorphism.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you not use $k$-linearity of your map, and comparing dimensions?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I tried but I was unable to compute the dimension of $B$ as $k$-vector space. It seems to me that $1$ and $x$ should be a generating set, but I can't see it

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I feel dumb haha I just realised that it is obvious that the dimension of $B$ as a $k$-vector space is $\leq 2$, thus the conclusion is obvious from this.